# How to compile on a Mac after upgrade to Maverick (OS 10.9.2)

Tags: mac, mactex

When I try compiling a document after upgrading to Maverick, I get the following error: 
"Can't find required tool.
`/usr/texbin/pdflatex` does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the macports or fink distributions."

I see from a previous thread that there is a package called FixMacTeX2013.pkg that would fix this problem. However, it does not seem to be on my system and I cannot find where to download it. 
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have this directory? `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`

Answer (score 5):

I just replace `/usr/texbin` by `/Library/Tex/texbin` in the preferences of Texshop, then this problem is fixed on my Macbook.

Comment: in the preferences of Texshop.

Comment: You might want to consolidate your two logon ids.  I understand "the staff" can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is an item of MacTeX itself. Once MacTeX properly installed, `FixMacTeX2013.pkg` is located in the `/Applications/TeX` directory.

By the way, at each OSX major system update, it is recommended to re-install MacTeX from scratch.

Comment: I don't agree with the second paragraph.

Comment: @egreg: Almost each time I made a major update on my system, there were problems with the links towards the TeX binaries, as for the OP… No idea why, to be honest. But theses problems were solved by reinstalling MacTeX.

Comment: @fpast: I didn't find the FixMacTeX2013.pkg so I reinstalled MacTeX and everything now seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have also updated your MacTeX. Install MacTex-2014 and the fixMacTex2014.pkg that comes with it. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed MacTex on Mavericks and `/usr/texbin` was added to my PATH.  In there I saw 23 links to `pdftex` (`ls -l | grep pdftex`).  However `pdflatex` was not one of them. Fixed my problem with the following:

```
# cd /usr/texbin
# sudo ln -s pdftex pdflatex
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, please follow the below steps:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type which pdftex.
3. This shall give you the file location.
4. If you did not find, look into following libraries - `/Library/Tex/texbin or /opt/local/bin/pdftex` (I found it in /Library/Tex/texbin)
5. Now go to, `TexShop` --> `Prefrences` --> `Engine` --> replace `/usr/texbin` by `/Library/Tex/texbin`.