# pdf doesn't regenerate after upgrading mac to mavericks

Tags: pdf, texshop

I just upgraded my mac to mavericks and latex is not working anymore. Since I'm really no computer pro I have no idea how to make it work again. though everything is still there it's not regenerating the `.pdf` document saying:

> /Users/clararohl/Library/TeXShop/Engines/alles.engine: line 3:
>   pdflatex: command not found
>   /Users/clararohl/Library/TeXShop/Engines/alles.engine: line 4: bibtex:
>   command not found
>   /Users/clararohl/Library/TeXShop/Engines/alles.engine: line 5:
>   makeindex: command not found
>   /Users/clararohl/Library/TeXShop/Engines/alles.engine: line 6:
>   pdflatex: command not found
>   /Users/clararohl/Library/TeXShop/Engines/alles.engine: line 7:
>   pdflatex: command not found

How can I fix this? i have no idea!!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175598/how-to-compile-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-maverick-os-10-9-2 help?

Comment: Try reinstalling latex. The easiest way is using the [mactex](http://tug.org/mactex/) package.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall although this should work. You just need to remake the symbolic links which MacTeX relies on. Your installation is likely still there at `/usr/local/texlive`. It is the symbol links such as `/usr/texbin` which may have gone missing.

Comment: @Andrew is right. Be sure you update to MacTex-2014 and run the fixMacTeX2014.pkg as well (it downloads with the MacTeX and is found in the Applications>TeX folder). Save yourself a lot of hacking AND be working with the latest MacTeX release.