# no tex installation detected on RStudio after OS X 10.10 yosemite upgrade

Tags: mac, mactex, knitr, rstudio

I upgraded my MAC to OS X 10.10 yosemite today. Now, when I run RStudio and try to use Knitr to compile pdf, it says no text installation detected. So, I did the following steps sequentially.

1. Install MacTeX
2. Install RStudio 2014-10-14 version (I had older version before)

This solved my problem. I have no idea how my problem is solved. My question: Is it the only way to solve this problem? Or is there any way I can configure RStudio to detect where Tex installation is?

I have looked at some discussions on previous MAC OS X upgrade with Tex problems [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175598/how-to-compile-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-maverick-os-10-9-2) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142054/unable-to-run-context-pdftex-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks). I have also found some good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229657/rstudio-cant-find-latex-after-mavericks-update) which appears to be much close to my problem. But I wanted to have a definite clue on what is going on. I appreciate if anyone can give me some hints.

Comment: I found two solutions. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090788/sweave-not-working-in-rstudio-found-path-but-how-to-set or https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201688563-Problem-with-Mac-Yosemite-Beta-and-RStudio-not-finding-TeX-distribution

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/texbin/pdflatex /usr/bin/pdflatex
```

this worked for me. the upgrade to yosemite broke the link and it needs to redone :)

you may first check for pdflatex in `/usr/bin/`. This is where rStudio looks.

```
cd /usr/bin/    
ls -a
```